# Cant get two column layout to work

Tags: html, css, layout, css-float

I am trying to make a simple two column layout but it seems harder than I thought..

It needs to have:

- A fixed width 300px left column
- A right column which fills up the
  rest of the page - whatever the
  window size
- Both column divs must touch the
  bottom of the page

The bit I had trouble with was the third bullet point, if I used floats then the right column would always wrap under the left column and I couldn't get them both to be flush against the bottom of the page!

And I thought I needed to float the left column as setting the right to 100%-300px is impossible.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this - tested from IE6+ on and works.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
    html, body {height:100%;position:relative;margin:0;padding:0;}
.side {float:left;width:300px;height:100%;background:red;}
.main {margin-left:300px;background:blue;height:100%;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="side">
       side content
</div>
<div class="main">
    content
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In this case it is more obvious to use id's instead of classes for your div's.

Comment: When I put text into .main that is longer than one page the div does not expand and the background stops.

Comment: @Jleagle Well you didn't specify that. YOu can try faux columns for that http://line25.com/articles/create-sidebars-of-equal-height-with-faux-columns - with abit of customization it should work.

Comment: @Midas It doesn't really matter - the question is about layout not about ids and classes - I assume he already has basic understanding of css if he's asking such a question.

Answer (score 0):

**CSS:**

```
#main, * html #left, * html #right { display:inline; height:100% }
#main { display:table }
#left, #right { display:table-cell }
#left { width:300px }
```

The `* html #left` is for IE, so that it is forced to use `display:inline; height:100%`. IE doesn't seem to support `display:table-cell`.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="left"></div>
    <div id="right"></div>
</div>
```